# Determining the token address of a cNFT to display it on solscan

Tags: cnft

I have the use case of displaying the link to a cNFT once it is minted, example link is: https://solscan.io/token/4xFqEN4ff7ed38Fqf7Fo8VdcN2pK1jsNcd8k9RMQ88fV#txs
I am using `@metaplex-foundation/mpl-bubblegum` javascript library to mint cNFTs. How can I programatically determine the address before or after cNFT mint, using which I can create the solscan link to the cNFT.